# Pipe xargs to sed and mv command

Tags: shell, xargs

I have to do some complex regex on a file and then move the files.
I am thinking of xargs since it seemed very elegant for the job.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | sed 's/[[complex-regex]]//g' | xargs -0 -I file mv file output-of-sed
```

I have googled for hours but the syntax that is eluding me is how to get the output of sed as the second argument to mv command above.

I am totally clueless but charmed by the magic of xargs is this even possible what I am trying to do ?

Comment: What does the output of the `sed` command look like?  Does each line contain the original name and the "as modified" name (with the names separated by a blank and the old name before the new name)?  Are the names always guaranteed to be different?  Are any names going to have spaces or newlines or other irksome characters in them?  Assuming you generate 'old new' per line, and no white space in the file names, you could probably use `xargs` working per line.  Even that isn't guaranteed.  Incidentally, your `sed` command should probably be made aware of the null delimiters.

Comment: Hi Jonathan the output of sed command is very different from the input file for example it removes multiple spaces and replaces them with a single underscore

Comment: FIne, but … well, the multiple spaces bit makes life ghastly.  Anyway, if you were going to move a file manually, you'd use `mv old-name new-name`.  If you never deliver `old-name` to `xargs`, how is the `mv` command executed by `xargs` going to know what the old name was?  Then the fact that you're working with spaces would mean you'd need to tell `sed` to work with null-terminated lines, and you'd have to print the old name, then mangle it and priunt the new line, and then tell `xargs` to work with pairs of consecutive names.  But the answer you've been given is pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 1):

When complex regex is needed to rename or move dirs or files, then [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) is the way to go :

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 -exec rename -0 's@[[complex-regex]]@@' {} \;
```

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl rename` executable.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: Hi Giles Thanks for taking a timeout and looking at this My apologies i should have mentioned that I don't have the rename utility on this box as I don't own the box

Comment: As explained, it's just a script downloadable with no dependencies (just need Perl)

Comment: Hi Giles I totally understand I will try to coax the admin but this is server i have my apprehension that the might sys admins if they allow my humble request :)

Comment: You can even place this script as simple user and put it in the PATH variable

Comment: Or simply: `wget https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL; chmod +x rename.PL; ./rename.PL`